# Disposing bitmap in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, dispose, using

I'm writing a .dll in which I'm using the following method:

```
public static Bitmap Merge(Bitmap largeBmp, Bitmap smallBmp)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(largeBmp.Width + smallBmp.Width, Math.Max(largeBmp.Height, smallBmp.Height));
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.DrawImage(largeBmp, 0, 0);
        g.DrawImage(smallBmp, largeBmp.Width, 0);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

I want know if calling this method many times (let's say 10000 times) will cause memory problems. If yes, how can I avoid it? Do I have to call `dispose` on the `bitmap` objects?

**EDIT**: I'm calling that method in this way inside of a `while` statement:

```
writerOut.WriteVideoFrame(Merge(lastFrame, lastColorFrame));
```

How can I dispose the `Bitmap` that is returned from the `Merge` method (after I have used it)?

Comment: As you are returning the newly created bitmap, you cannot dispose it within the method (or else it would not be usable any more by the callers of the method). Therefore, it is within the responsibility of the *callers* to dispose of the bitmap once it is not required any longer.

Comment: You should dispose classes that implement IDisposable anyway. Apart from that, you shouldn't try to optimize prematurely unless you actually find that you do have a problem.

Comment: Using statement is alternative for try-catch having only dispose method in finally block.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I generally agree with the latter statement, though I would place an emphasis on the first part; calling `Dispose` on a disposable object is usually not "optimization", and not premature, either.

Comment: I have editet my question. @O.R.Mapper I'm calling it without disposing it. How can I modify my call?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper didn't say it is. I said "apart from that" prematurely worrying about memory issues that may never arise is not useful. For example, finding a way to _avoid_ creating 10K bitmaps is more important than worrying when the GC will claim the memory of those 10K objects. 10K ops may or may not be an issue, depending on the application (client, server) and user expectations. With backgound GC in 4.5 you may not even notice anything. 10K undisposed GDI handles on the other hand is a VERY big issue

Comment: @AftabAhmed: That is not technically correct. A try-catch block is used for exception handling, whereas a using block is used for disposing objects.

Comment: i have read it on MSDN that if your try catch block is only responsible for disposing objects you can use Using instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are returning the bitmap to be used by the caller - then it is the callers responsibility to dispose the object when they're finished with it.

By using the 'using' statement you've already done all you can to ensure that the graphics object is properly disposed.  In theory you should be fine - I wouldn;t worry about that unless it becomes a specific problem - then come back and ask how to solve it.

With regard to your edit - unless 'writerOut.WriteVideoFrame' disposes of the bimtap when its finished with it then this will cause a problem.

you could either do :

```
var bm = Merge( ... );
writerOut.WriteVideoFrame(bm);
bm.Dispose();
```

or

```
 using(var bm=merge(...))
     writerOut.WriteVideoFrame(bm)
```

Comment: Thank you. As said in the EDIT of my question maybe I'm calling that method in the wrong way. Right?

Comment: +1 Yeah. all bitmaps must be disposed - but if the reason for a method to exist is to return a usable bitmap, this can not be disposed per definition. Whoever calls that method must be made aware of his responsibility (via comment in the documentation) to dispose the bitmap when done.

Comment: Bitmap is an unmanaged resource so after calling Dispose, you must release all references to it. The safer way is to implement a dispose method.

Answer (score 3):

The `Bitmap` instance needs to be disposed after use. The easiest way to do that is a `using` block:

```
using (var bmp = Merge(lastFrame, lastColorFrame)) {
    writerOut.WriteVideoFrame(bmp);
}
```

The `using` block is a shorthand for a `try-finally` block that calls `Dispose` in the `finally` part, so even if an exception occurs during `WriteVideoFrame`, the bitmap will be correctly disposed of.