# Do i have to dispose the Bitmap in the method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, dispose

The method return the Bitmap variable nb, do i need to dispose this variable somewhere in the method and if i do where to do it ?

```
public Bitmap cropAtRect(Bitmap b, Rectangle r)
        {
            Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb))
            {
                g.DrawImage(b, -r.X, -r.Y);
                return nb;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's the code that receives the Bitmap that needs to dispose of it, not this method. It's important that it does, a Bitmap holds unmanaged resources, the GC cannot help you here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disposing bitmap in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987905/disposing-bitmap-in-c-sharp-application) or [When disposing bitmaps or not in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53483621/150605)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of disposing is to release resources held by an object. Disposing is something you do when you're finished with an object. If your method is returning that `Bitmap` then it obviously expects that `Bitmap` to be used after the method completes, so disposing it in the method wouldn't make any sense. What would probably make sense is the code that calls your method would use the `Bitmap` it returns and then dispose it, e.g.

```cs
Bitmap bmp;
Rectangle rect;

// ...

using (var newBmp = cropAtRect(bmp, rect))
{
    // Use newBmp here.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

c# should take care of that for you some time after the last reference to the bitmap goes out of scope.  If you are worried about it you can watch your memory use while debugging or write a test case that creates many bitmaps with your function.

Comment: .NET won't take care of freeing unmanaged resources for you. That's why objects that use unmanaged resources, such as `Bitmap`, implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Is .NET's bitmap unmanaged?  I'm not sure that it is.

Comment: [`Bitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.8) is derived from [`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8) whose [`Dispose` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.dispose?view=netframework-4.8) is pretty adamant about disposing unmanaged resources. The remarks suggests that GC will _eventually_ call `Finalize` which will free the resources.

Comment: @Pete, any .NET class is managed, by definition. A managed object can hold unmanaged resources though, and a `Bitmap` holds a GDI+ image handle, if I'm not mistaken. When you dispose it, that is what gets released back to the OS.

Comment: For that matter it will also get cleaned up when your application exits, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't be proactive in `Dispose()`ing when possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).